# Mysterious behaviour of footnotes with hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I have an example, stripped to absolute minimum, showing the mysterious influence of switching `colorlinks=false` to `colorlinks=true` in the `hyperref` package on some footnotes. In this document, a footnote is called from one-column text on the top of the page. It is attached to "Author". `\onecolumngrid` or `{widetext}` give the same results.

In case of `colorlinks=false`, everything is working properly; the mail address is active, but is boxed. If the `colorlinks=true` option is chosen, the footnote is not only invisible, but totally non-existent. Its place is filled with ordinary main text. The same is true when the footnote contains plain text, without link.

How to solve this problem and get footnotes with coloured links?

```
\documentclass[A4paper,aps,twocolumn,article,nofootinbib,nobibnotes,twoside,titlepage
]{revtex4}

\usepackage[pdftex,%pdftitle={},pdfauthor={},
colorlinks=false, pdfborder={1 0 1},
%colorlinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 1},
urlcolor=magenta, linkcolor=green, citecolor=green, raiselinks=false,
hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\onecolumngrid
{\Huge wwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwww wwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww}\par\vspace*{0.5cm}

 \large\textsc{Author\footnote{corresponding author; e-mail:\tt~\href
 {mailto:ddd@mailer}{mail address}\\}}\\\baselineskip13pt{Afiliation}\par\vspace*{0.5cm}

\normalsize wwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
\par\vspace*{1.5cm}

\twocolumngrid

\section{first chapter}
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 

wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 
wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww 

end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to debug the problem, this answer contains a MWE with reduced complexity.
The example shows that the problem does not depend on `hyperref`.
The following MWE

```
\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

AAA\footnote{BBB}

\twocolumngrid

CCC

\end{document}
```

shows that the problem only depends on option `nofootinbib`, package `color` and the switch to `\twocolumngrid`.